# Accurate -2V reference

Tags: voltage, multimeter, zener, voltage-reference

I have an old Keithley 175A multimeter that has been suffering from a bit of drift lately.  Internally it uses a 6.35V zener and a couple of resistors to create a -2V reference, but the zener is obsolete and no longer available.  So I was thinking about replacing the reference circuit with something more modern but I can't seem to find a -2V reference...most of them are +2.048V.  Looking for suggestions to construct a highly accurate -2V reference.

[image]

( Scan from http://www.utwente.nl/tnw/onderwijs/practica_tnw/doc/apparatuur/multimeters/keithley175.pdf )

Comment: What internal power rails do you have inside the meter?

Comment: You need to find out (or make up) some specification for accuracy, drift etc.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer was given before the OP kindly changed the requirements from +2 volts to - 2 volts therefore it's still under construction**

Use the 2.048 volt reference and a potential divider after the 2.048 volt output to produce precisely 2V. Then using an inverting configuration op-amp running from negative and positive rails invert the 2V to -2V - possible op-amp choice is the [AD8657](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD8657_8659.pdf)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHGHBB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: As long as this opamp can be powered by his system -- he wants a negative vref so this amplifier may be used with a gain of -1 (or -2000/2048) [edit battle]

Comment: @HL-SDK - read my opening line dude!!!

Comment: EDIT BATTLE! :D

Comment: Thank you all kindly for your suggestions.  Fortunately I have a still very accurate Keithley 197 multimeter to check the voltages of the circuits posted and have ordered 2.048V reference and the AD8657 opamp.  I've also ordered the Zeners suggested and will try prototyping a reference circuit with those as well.  The most stable and accurate circuit will win the prize.  BTW I think I edited my original question just a few minutes after realizing that the references was negative...man you guys are quick!

Answer (score 3):

The old temperature- compensated zeners were pretty good - you can get 6.2V 1N829As from e14 for about $7 ea.  They're 5ppm/K.

Band gap references might not be as good and would tend to be noisy.

A shunt reference could probably drop in, in place of the zener, with the change of the divider resistors (say to give you -2.000V rather than -4.096V (and change the dropping resistor to reduce the bias current). Eg. [LM4030](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4030.pdf). Since they're two-terminal you don't need to worry about the reference being negative.

Suggest you post a snippet of the schematic that includes the reference and what it is connected to (I would assume an analog switch connected to an integrator circuit).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cheap bandgap solution that would get your meter going again.  But you'll have to do the analysis to see how accuracy is impacted.  The references in old meters weren't chosen by accident.

[image]

Comment: I know this is an old post, but would you mind showing how you get -2V. I'm using the "standard" TL431 equation and not getting it.  These negative voltages sometimes mess with my head.

Comment: Notice that it's a TLV431.  Standard TL431 won't regulate below 2.5 V.  TLV431 has a reference of 1.24 V.

Comment: It's just a voltage divider, trying to make 1.24V between "ref" and "anode".  So Vref = Vout * 1240 / (1240+760), or Vout = Vref  * (1240+760) / 1240, or Vout = 1.24 * (1240+760)/1240 = 2.0 V.

Comment: 1.24V was it!  Thanks I did miss that.  So \$Vout=1.24V*(1+\frac{760}{1240})=2.0V\$